# Display start and end dates for percent diff (in Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I have a dataset, df, where I wish to find the percent diff and diff. I wish to look at the earlier date and compare this value to the next date that is consecutive to it. The desired output should show the dates that are being compared.

```
 id    date         value

 1     11/01/2020   10
 2     11/01/2020   5
 1     10/01/2020   20
 2     10/01/2020   30
 1     09/01/2020   15
 2     09/01/2020   10
 3     11/01/2020   5
```

***Desired output***

```
  id    startdate       enddate           diff     percent


  1     09/01/2020      10/01/2020        5         33                 
  1     10/01/2020      11/01/2020       -10       -50
  2     09/01/2020      10/01/2020        20        200               
  2     10/01/2020      11/01/2020       -25       -83.33
  3     11/01/2020      11/01/2020        0         0
```

I am wanting to look at one group at a time and compare the previous value to the next value and find the percent increase and diff.

***For example***,

***ID 1, from 09/01/2020 to 10/01/2020*** : goes from ***15 to 20***,
giving a difference of ***5***
***percent difference is 33%***

***from 10/01/2020  to 11/01/2020:*** goes from ***20 to 10,***
***difference of ***-10*** and a ***50% percent difference.******

***This works well*** thanks to a member on this platform, ***however, how do I display both dat***es?

```
result = (df.sort_values(["id", "date", "value"])
              # use this later to drop the first row per group
              # if number is greater than 1, else leave as-is
      .assign(counter=lambda x: x.groupby("id").date.transform("size"),
              date_shift=lambda x: x.groupby(["id"]).date.shift(1),
              value_shift=lambda x: x.groupby("id").value.shift(1),
              diff=lambda x: x.value - x.value_shift,
              percent=lambda x: x["diff"].div(x.value_shift).mul(100).round(2))
       # here is where the counter column becomes useful
       # drop rows where date_shift is null and counter is > 1
       # this way if number of rows in the group is just one it is kept, 
       # if greater than one, the first row is dropped, 
       # as the first row would have nulls due to the `shift` method.
      .query("not (date_shift.isna() and counter>1)")
      .loc[:, ["id", "date", "diff", "percent"]]
      .fillna(0))

  result
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

No magic. Just do `groupby-shift` to produce the columns one by one as required.

### Data

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
id    date         value
1     11/01/2020   10
2     11/01/2020   5
1     10/01/2020   20
2     10/01/2020   30
1     09/01/2020   15
2     09/01/2020   10
3     11/01/2020   5
"""), sep=r"\s{2,}", engine="python")

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

### Code

```
# sort and groupby    
df2 = df.sort_values(["id", "date", "value"])
gp_obj = df2.groupby("id")

# produce the required columns
df2["startdate"] = gp_obj["date"].shift()
df2["diff"] = gp_obj["value"].diff()
df2["percent"] = df2["diff"] / df2["value"].shift() * 100

# drop NA rows and reorganize
df2.rename(columns={"date": "enddate"}, inplace=True)
df2 = df2[["id", "startdate", "enddate", "diff", "percent"]][~df2["diff"].isna()]
```

### Output

```
print(df2)
   id  startdate    enddate  diff     percent
2   1 2020-09-01 2020-10-01   5.0   33.333333
0   1 2020-10-01 2020-11-01 -10.0  -50.000000
3   2 2020-09-01 2020-10-01  20.0  200.000000
1   2 2020-10-01 2020-11-01 -25.0  -83.333333
```

Comment: hi @sammywemmy is there a way to add the start and end date within your code in the above post? (I like that there is a counter inside of the code)